# Central limit theorem approximation of distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

I am doing a question which asks for an approximation of the distribution of X, which is the number of successes out of 50 independent trials with probability 0.4, using the central limit theorem. Then the question asks the probability that the number of successes is less than 10 using this approximate distribution.

So the average of the sum $S_{50}=\sum_{i=1}^{50} X_i$ can be standardized, and then follows a standard normal distribution:

$$\frac{S_{50}-50E(X)}{\sqrt{50Var(X)}} \simeq N(0,1)$$

From this point, I think the probability that the number of successes is less than 10 is:

$$P(S_{50})=P(\frac{S_{50}-50E(X)}{\sqrt{50Var(X)}}\leq\frac{10-50\cdot20}{\sqrt{50\cdot 12}})$$

Where, on the right side, 10 is the number of successes, $E(X)$ is $np=50\cdot 0.4=20$, and the variance is $npq=12$. These values are from the binomial distribution. Am I correct in calculating $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ in this way? It seems that these values must be calculated from a binomial distribution. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You double counted $50E(X)$ and $50V(X)$. This because $S_{50}$ is a binomial, sum of 50 iid bernulli, thus in this version of CLT mean and variance are referred to the bernulli.

One way (not absolutely accurate is this)

$$\mathbb{P}(S<10)=\mathbb{P}\left[Z<\frac{10-50\cdot0.4}{\sqrt{50\cdot0.4\cdot0.6}}\right]=\Phi(-2.88)\approx0.0019$$

This result is not quite accurate. To realize that, the exact value using the binomial is

$$\mathbb{P}(S<10)\approx 0.0008$$

To improve our CLT approx, just use the Continuity Correction Factor obtaining

$$\mathbb{P}(S<10)=\mathbb{P}\left[Z<\frac{9.5-50\cdot0.4}{\sqrt{50\cdot0.4\cdot0.6}}\right]=\Phi(-3.031)\approx0.0012$$

---

To understand this reasoning I suggest you to calculate, for example, $P(S<20)$ so you will appreciate the best approximation I showed you. In fact, with the first approximation you get

$$\mathbb{P}(S<20)=\mathbb{P}(Z<0)=0.5$$

while the exact result with the binomial is $0.4465$

Now using the continuity correction factor you get

$$\mathbb{P}(S<20)=\mathbb{P}\left(Z<\frac{19.5-20}{3.464}\right)=\Phi(-0.14434)\approx0.4426$$

which is very close to the exact result

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I needed to realize that each random variable is Bernoulli distributed, not binomial. Something just occurred to me, which is the formula for standardizing $\bar{X}$ : $(\frac{\bar{X}-E(X_1)}{\sqrt{Var(X_1)/n}})$ with the denominator divided by $n$? Normally to standardize you just subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation, right?

Comment: @fmtcs ; that's correct! this one is another version of the same CLT. I prefer the former because it is more suitable to me when applying the continuity correction factor but anyway...use the version you are more familiar with

Comment: but I don't understand why that $/n$ is there in the first place, because it seems to me that $\bar{X}$ is not standardized if you multiply the numerator by $\sqrt{n}$ ?

Comment: @fmtcs :A version of CLT is

$$\frac{\Sigma_i x_i -n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}}N(0;1)$$

if you divide numerator and denominator by $n$ you obtain
$$\frac{\overline{X}_n -\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}\xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}}N(0;1)$$

which is your latter version.